# Rails Omniauth facebook not returning info fields other than default fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm using facebook authentication for my Rails 5 app. I want to fetch user details other than email. But it's not returning the specified fields.
Here's my config for devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP ID", "APP Secret", scope: 'email', secure_image_url: true, :image_size => 'large', auth_type: 'https',info_fields: 'email,name,first_name,last_name,gender',
client_options: {
    site: "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0",
    authorize_url: "https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth"
    }
```

Please help me to get out of this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out the documentation for the [omniauth-facebook gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring), it seems like you're not getting your extra info fields because you forgot to request the permissions from the users in `scope`.

Try adding `public_profile` to `scope`, like so:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP ID", "APP Secret", scope: 'email,public_profile,user_gender', secure_image_url: true, :image_size => 'large', auth_type: 'https',info_fields: 'email,name,first_name,last_name,gender',
client_options: {
  site: "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0",
  authorize_url: "https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth"
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I tried the same with "first_name". But I'm getting an error facebook that "Invalid Scope: first_name
"

Comment: Ok, try replacing `name,first_name,last_name` with `public_profile`

Comment: It is working fine with your suggestion in development mode. But I'm facing issue. After a lot of research, I came to know that  facebook is asking to submit my app for review. Until then, I will not get the required info from FB. Anyways, Thank You for your help

Comment: @manoharvadapalli Do you absolutely need to get the gender field? Because I think if you only ask for email and public profile data (and skip user gender), you won't need to ask for a review: ("Review is not required to ask for the two basic permissions: public_profile and email.", from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review)